# Stack Exchange SQL samples

Tags: discussion, sql

I swear I saw this on one of Stack Exchange sites, but can't find it. There was a section full of SQL query samples, like which users got most upvotes for last 2 weeks and so on. Does anyone know where is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer

http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: also linked in the footer of every page as "data"

Comment: @Jeff ah, easy to miss. Too many links :-)